# Comparison of string in SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite

I have a problem with comparison of two string in SQL Lite. 
This query works

```
Cursor cur=myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * from usluga where usluga_nazwa = 'malowanie farba dekoral'" ,null);
```

But this one

```
String tmp="malowanie farba dekoral";
Cursor cur=myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * from usluga where usluga_nazwa = "+tmp+"" ,null);
```

didn't work

> Error: SQLite exceptions: near "farba" syntax error.

I tried to use LIKE operator but didn't work too.

How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String literals in SQL are delimited by single quotes, which you forgot to add in you second example. Just add them, and you should be fine:

```
String tmp="malowanie farba dekoral";
Cursor cur=myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * from usluga where usluga_nazwa = '"+tmp+"'" ,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

1st one becomes something like

usluga_nazwa = 'some string'

2nd one becomes

usluga_nazwa = some string

which gives syntax error

Just add parentheses around the string 
value (tmp) in the second SQL query.

```
String tmp="malowanie farba dekoral";
Cursor cur=myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * from usluga where usluga_nazwa = '"+tmp+"'" ,null);
```

Also note that if your string value (tmp) itself contains 
a ' then you will run into a problem probably. And the 
solution for that is to escape the ' in the string value.